# Get selected ion-checkbox from json array angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I have the following array:

```
$scope.profile.preferencias = [7,5,3,8,4];
```

**EDIT**
My Category array looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "descricao": "Entomologia",
    "dataCriacao": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "isActive": true,
    "isFixed": true
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "descricao": "Fisiologia",
    "dataCriacao": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "isActive": true,
    "isFixed": true
  }
]
```

My ion-checkbox looks like this:

```
<ion-checkbox ng-repeat="category in categories | toArray | orderBy:'descricao'" name="group" ng-model="profile.preferencias[category.id]">{{category.descricao}}</ion-checkbox>
```

The output selected is:

```
{
   "7": true,
   "5": false,
   "3": true
}
```

How can i sent only the number to my json, so it will save like the $scope above, and when the page is reloaded, the checkboxes comes back checked?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please share your $scope.categories array?

Comment: Hi, added the category array, thanks

Comment: You need a number array [selected category Ids] right?

Comment: Correct, and then i'll save it like the $scope.profile.preferencias, but i need the checkboxes to be checked when reloading the page

Comment: Can you create a plunker/Fiddle example?

Answer (score 1):

i am using same things in my app.

```
<div ng-repeat="day in days" class="week_days">
        <ion-checkbox ng-model="day.select" style="border:none">{{day.name}}</ion-checkbox>
</div>
```

and JSON data  is

```
$scope.days = [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Mon",
            "select": true
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Tue",
            "select": true
        }, {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Wed",
            "select": true
        }, {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Thu",
            "select": true
        }, {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Fri",
            "select": true
        }, {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "Sat",
            "select": true
        }, {
            "id": 0,
            "name": "Sun",
            "select": true
        }];
```

the above $scope variable is default checkbox is selected. if you want not default checkbox is selected then changed **"select":false"**.

Thanks,